# Issue with getting Java to go to URL

Tags: java, android, arduino

I am having an issue getting this button I have in my application I made to just visit the link so that my Arduino can see that someone went to the link and turn on the [LED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode). How do I to fix this?

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.power) {
    //new HttpPost("192.168.0.107/digitalWrite/8/1");
    new DefaultHttpClient();
    new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.107/digitalWrite/8/1");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Power", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    .show();
}
```

Comment: Can you post more information about what you are trying to do?

Comment: what i am trying to do is be able to just visit the link which i have up there as if i went into my internet browser and just opened a link and visited a site and that's all i want it to do. But i want to be able to do that without having a web browser pop up so one of those things that goes on in the background.

Comment: I assume you want to do it in Android. Is that correct? If yes, then why did you add Arduino as a tag?

Comment: yes i just now noticed i forgot to mention that its so that i can communicate with my arduino Ethernet shield over one link when i hit a button on my android app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Apache HTTP client that comes with Android.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
```

Also make sure have added the following permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```